# Prevent or remove p tag placed around images in CKEditor4

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

My issue is `<p>` tags are being placed around uploaded image in **CKEditor4**. Not a huge issue normally but starting to throw CSS off in some templates (like bootstrap).

Currently I get this after uploading an image:

```
<p><img src="images/example.jpg"></p>
```

Like to have only:

```
<img src="images/example.jpg">
```

I have tried adding (no success for images):

```
config.autoParagraph = false;
```

I have visited many threads here on stackoverflow and most all refer to WordPress which I am not using. The CKEditor is in a simple CMS for school blogs on a local network.

Found reference to a WordPress plugin that some say will work (strip out all WP ref), but that has failed miserably:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Paragraph Remover
Description: Removes paragraphs around images
Version: 0.1
Author: Martin Vlcek
Author URI: http://mvlcek.bplaced.net
*/

# get correct id for plugin
$thisfile = basename(__FILE__, ".php");

# register plugin
register_plugin(
    $thisfile, 
    'PRemover',     
    '0.1',      
    'Martin Vlcek',
    'http://mvlcek.bplaced.net', 
    'Removes paragraphs around images',
    '',
    ''  
);

# activate filter
add_filter('content','premover_replace');

function premover_replace($content) {
  return preg_replace_callback("/<p>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*(<a[^>]+>)?(?:\s|&nbsp;)*(<img[^>]+>)(?:\s|&nbsp;)*(<\/a>)?(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/p>/",'premover_replace_match',$content);
}

function premover_replace_match($match) {
  return $match[1].@$match[2].@$match[3];
}
```

Cannot find solution and hoping for some input. Either a plugin, javascript or PHP, it does not matter.